# Benefits of increasing DB initial size

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm a new DBA and have installed spotlight to monitor my DB's. I was advised by a senior DBA to increase the initial size of my DB, but he could not explain me properly the reason/benefits of this increase. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Tag dbms used, this is a product specific question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason would be fragmentation of files. The big initial size will protect you from the issue.

Additionally when your database grows, it costs - database performance is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because when initial size is exceeded, the files on the file system need to be increased. This leads to fragmented files on the disk, because most often it cannot get more space immediately following the already allocated space.

Sometimes files grow in percent, which causes even more fragmentation when you start with a very small initial size.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that when a file has to grow, all database operations will stop until the file has grown by the amount specified in the autogrowth settings of the database, this is a costly operation and can take some time depending on the size of the database, the autogrowth settings (imagine the time it could take to grow a DB by 10% if it is already 2TB in size, all your queries would have to wait for that to finish, hence why fixed amounts are generally better than percentages), the speed of the storage and whether instant file initialization is enabled for the SQL instance.

It is much better to size a database appropriately from the beginning to avoid these issues.

Fragmentation is not as much of an issue as it is made out to be, generally on a production SQL server, the database files are on their own volume with nothing else writing to them, so contiguous space is not an issue, also the issue of fragmentation gets a whole lot more complex when you take into account that the drive could be an iSCSI LUN, you have no idea of the physical file layout (NetApps for instance can write all over the place with the Write Anywhere File Layout, WAFL).

Generally file/index fragmentation in SQL server is blown out of proportion when it comes to performance, it is very rarely in my experience even close to being the main factor when it comes to troubleshooting performance.